# How Magento generates Product Images Cache?

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.6

We have uploaded the product images via Magento 2 admin-panel for our client site. For checking purpose, we have downloaded the image (which we have uploaded) from the front-end of the site. Upon checking, we have noticed that the size of the product image (original size is 530KB) reduced to 230KB.

While we investigate this, we have seen that the image which was appeared on the front-end was from product cache.

So, my question is, why the product cache images are displaying instead of the original size of the image?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

Product cache images are the default feature of Magento.

This is cache images are created on basically at the category and product pages are loaded at frontend.

And frontend cache images size depend on theme setting https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

Also using the command line `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` you can generate the cache issue.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I understand now, product cache images are the default feature of Magento. But my question is, we have product images that are having a bigger file size. In this case, do I need to use any image optimizer plugin to optimize the images? Please suggest.